# Removing state machine from a particular instances of Active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, state-machine

How to remove state machine from a instance of ActiveRecord . 
For ex

```
Class X < ActiveRecord::Base 
state_machine 
## rest of code
end

x = X.new

x.state_machines = nil ##something like this
```

Now i want to remove the state_machine for some particular instances of X without touching the existing code .

Can We do that ?? 
I am using [pluginaweek](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) state machine .

Comment: Why do you want to remove it? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't think you can remove it, but you can create it dynamically, see [Static / Dynamic definitions](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine#static--dynamic-definitions)

Comment: weird approach, potential code smell

Answer (score 0):

The approach seems to be very strange, because we think that the same problem, which you didn't tell us, can be solved with more pleasing way. However you are able to remove the getter `#state_machine` (or setter if needed) in runtime for specific instance. The sample is:

```
class A
   def a 
   end
end

a1 = A.new
a2 = A.new
a1.a # => nil
a2.a # => nil
a1.instance_eval { undef :a } # => nil 
a1.a # => NoMethodError: undefined method `a' for #<A:0x80684f4>
a2.a # => nil
```

With the same approach you are able to redefine any instance method in an instnce of the class.